# Confidence intervals in python plotly

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, linear-regression, scatter-plot

Hi is there any method for plotting confidence interval lines in plotly around predicted line in scatterplot in python in plotly.I am not able to find anything relevant to it in docs

Comment: This should get you there: [Plotly: How to make a figure with multiple lines and shaded area for standard deviations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494278/plotly-how-to-make-a-figure-with-multiple-lines-and-shaded-area-for-standard-de/61501980#61501980)

Comment: Of course you can find relative documentation like [Continuous Error Bands in Python](https://plotly.com/python/continuous-error-bars/) in Plotly official website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends on the model. I am using Randon Forest to generate predictions (sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor) and I am using forestci package to plot ci of the prediction (http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/forest-confidence-interval/auto_examples/index.html)