# How to have 2 traces on y1 & y2 axis with highlight function in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I need to plot 2 traces, one on the left y-axis and one on the right and I would like to keep the highlight function. So the `data` argument is not the same for the two traces.

Is there a way to do that?

```
library(plotly)

## Data ################
tmp <- data.frame(timestamp = structure(c(1632132000, 1632139200, 1632146400, 1632153600, 1632160800, 1632168000, 
                                          1632175200, 1632182400, 1632189600, 1632196800, 1632204000, 1632211200, 
                                          1632132000, 1632139200, 1632146400, 1632153600, 1632160800, 1632168000,
                                          1632175200, 1632182400, 1632189600, 1632196800, 1632204000, 1632211200), 
                                        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin"), 
                  value = c(29.015, 25.724, 24.017, 25.118, 28.334, 30.408, 
                            32.046, 32.441, 29.463, 27.528, 24.136, 21.067, 27.352, 23.13, 
                            24.962, 24.558, 130.475, 148.465, 157.134, 149.983, 133.003, 
                            123.9, 117.334, 115.927), 
                  valuetype = c(rep("Type 1",12),rep("Type 2",12)),
                  route_name = rep("group 1", 24), 
                  value_color = c(rep("#e3a201", 12), rep("#FFBA00",12)))

## Plotly ###############
plot_ly(data = tmp) %>%
  highlight_key(~paste0(route_name, valuetype)) %>%
  ## 1 Trace ###################
  add_trace(
    data = tmp[tmp$valuetype %in% unique(tmp$valuetype)[[1]],],
    inherit = FALSE,
            x = ~timestamp, y = ~value,
            type = "scattergl", mode = "lines",
            name = ~paste(valuetype, route_name),
            color = ~I(value_color)) %>%
  ## 2 Trace ###################
  add_trace(
    data = tmp[tmp$valuetype %in% unique(tmp$valuetype)[[2]],],
    inherit = FALSE,
            x = ~timestamp, y = ~value,
            yaxis = "y2",
            type = "scattergl", mode = "lines",
            name = ~paste(valuetype, route_name),
            color = ~I(value_color)) %>%
  ## Layout for Group 1&2 ###################
  plotly::layout(xaxis = list(title = "Zeit", type = "date"),
                 yaxis = list(side ="left", title = "Y-Title"),
                 yaxis2 = list(side="right", overlaying = "y", title = "Y2-Title"),
                 margin = list(l=50,r=50,t=50,b=10),
                 legend = list(orientation = 'h', xanchor = 'center', x = 0.5, y = -0.2)) %>% 
    plotly::highlight(on = "plotly_hover", off = "plotly_doubleclick",
                      selected = attrs_selected(showlegend = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is an option for you, but if you use only a single `data` argument you can use `style` to assign a trace to another y-axis:

```
library(plotly)

## Data ################
tmp <- data.frame(timestamp = structure(c(1632132000, 1632139200, 1632146400, 1632153600, 1632160800, 1632168000, 
                                          1632175200, 1632182400, 1632189600, 1632196800, 1632204000, 1632211200, 
                                          1632132000, 1632139200, 1632146400, 1632153600, 1632160800, 1632168000,
                                          1632175200, 1632182400, 1632189600, 1632196800, 1632204000, 1632211200), 
                                        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin"), 
                  value = c(29.015, 25.724, 24.017, 25.118, 28.334, 30.408, 
                            32.046, 32.441, 29.463, 27.528, 24.136, 21.067, 27.352, 23.13, 
                            24.962, 24.558, 130.475, 148.465, 157.134, 149.983, 133.003, 
                            123.9, 117.334, 115.927), 
                  valuetype = c(rep("Type 1",12),rep("Type 2",12)),
                  route_name = rep("group 1", 24), 
                  value_color = c(rep("#e3a201", 12), rep("#FFBA00",12)))

## Plotly ###############
tmp %>% highlight_key(~paste0(route_name, valuetype)) %>%
plot_ly(
  x = ~timestamp, y = ~value,
  type = "scatter", mode = "lines", # "scattergl"
  name = ~paste(valuetype, route_name),
  color = ~I(value_color)) %>%
  ## assign trace 1 to y2
  style(yaxis = "y2", traces = 1) %>%
  ## Layout for Group 1&2 ###################
plotly::layout(xaxis = list(title = "Zeit", type = "date"),
               yaxis = list(side ="left", title = "Y-Title"),
               yaxis2 = list(side="right", overlaying = "y", title = "Y2-Title"),
               margin = list(l=50,r=50,t=50,b=10),
               legend = list(orientation = 'h', xanchor = 'center', x = 0.5, y = -0.2)) %>% 
  plotly::highlight(on = "plotly_hover", off = "plotly_doubleclick", selected = attrs_selected(showlegend = FALSE))
```

[image: result]

---

**Edit: Trace indices example:**

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

## Data ################
tmp <- data.frame(timestamp = structure(c(1632132000, 1632139200, 1632146400, 1632153600, 1632160800, 1632168000, 
                                          1632175200, 1632182400, 1632189600, 1632196800, 1632204000, 1632211200, 
                                          1632132000, 1632139200, 1632146400, 1632153600, 1632160800, 1632168000,
                                          1632175200, 1632182400, 1632189600, 1632196800, 1632204000, 1632211200,
                                          1632132000, 1632139200, 1632146400, 1632153600, 1632160800, 1632168000, 
                                          1632175200, 1632182400, 1632189600, 1632196800, 1632204000, 1632211200, 
                                          1632132000, 1632139200, 1632146400, 1632153600, 1632160800, 1632168000,
                                          1632175200, 1632182400, 1632189600, 1632196800, 1632204000, 1632211200), 
                                        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin"), 
                  value = c(c(29.015, 25.724, 24.017, 25.118, 28.334, 30.408, 
                            32.046, 32.441, 29.463, 27.528, 24.136, 21.067, 27.352, 23.13, 
                            24.962, 24.558, 130.475, 148.465, 157.134, 149.983, 133.003, 
                            123.9, 117.334, 115.927), c(29.015, 25.724, 24.017, 25.118, 28.334, 30.408, 
                                                        32.046, 3.441, 2.463, 2.528, 2.136, 2.067, 2.352, 23.13, 
                                                        24.962, 24.558, 13.475, 14.465, 15.134, 14.983, 13.003, 
                                                        123.9, 117.334, 115.927) + 50), 
                  valuetype = c(rep("Type 1",12), rep("Type 2", 12), rep("Type 3", 12), rep("Type 4", 12)),
                  route_name = rep("group 1", 48), 
                  value_color = c(rep("#e3a201", 12), rep("#FFBA00", 12), rep("red", 12), rep("darkgreen", 12)),
                  yaxis = c(rep("y", 12), rep("y2", 12), rep("y", 12), rep("y3", 12)))

setDT(tmp)
tmp[, trace_index := .GRP-1, by = .(route_name, valuetype)]

## Plotly ###############
shared_data <- highlight_key(tmp, ~paste0(route_name, valuetype))

fig <- plot_ly(data = shared_data,
               x = ~timestamp, y = ~value,
               type = "scatter", mode = "lines", # "scattergl"
               name = ~paste(valuetype, route_name),
               color = ~I(value_color))

if(any(tmp$yaxis != "y")){
  axesMapping <- unique(tmp[yaxis != "y", c("yaxis","trace_index")])
  
  # layout call to add the axis could be added here
  for(i in seq_len(NROW(axesMapping))){
    fig <- do.call(plotly::style, list(p = fig, yaxis = axesMapping[i,]$yaxis, traces = axesMapping[i,]$trace_index))
  }
}

## Layout for Group 1&2 ###################
plotly::layout(fig,
               xaxis = list(title = "Zeit", type = "date", domain = c(0, 0.75)),
               yaxis = list(side ="left", title = "Y-Title"),
               yaxis2 = list(side="right", overlaying = "y", title = "Y2-Title"),
               yaxis3 = list(side="right", overlaying = "y", anchor="free", position = 0.85, title = "Y3-Title"),
               margin = list(l=50,r=50,t=50,b=10),
               legend = list(orientation = 'h', xanchor = 'center', x = 0.5, y = -0.2)) %>% 
  plotly::highlight(on = "plotly_hover", off = "plotly_doubleclick", selected = attrs_selected(showlegend = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thats a nice idea, but I am not sure if I can use it, since the plot can have multiple traces, sometimes with second y-axis and sometimes not.. and I dont know if I can know upfront the trace-indices for y2.

Comment: The order of the trace index should correspond to the order of your data - so it should be possible. However, there is a limitation regarding [different trace types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58286368/9841389).

Comment: @SeGa I added a more sophisticated example regarding the trace indices.